# Git: same remote upstream for two local branches

Tags: git

I have two local branches, `master` and `dev`
When I write `git branch -v` I get

```
master    f83fskr [origin/master: ahead 2] some commit message
def       kfdsj42 other commit message
```

I want both branches to have `origin/master` as their upstream branch, so that it will show

```
master    f83fskr [origin/master: ahead 2] some commit message
def       kfdsj42 [origin/master: ahead 3] other commit message
```

And also so that I could use `git pull`, `git push` without specifying a branch.

How can I achieve this? (`-u` didn't work)

Comment: Have you tried `git checkout def; git branch -u origin/master`?

Comment: @SajibKhan it worked! thanks

Comment: Welcome, then I wrote an answer.

Comment: Please accept the solution if it solves your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout to `def` branch and *set-upstream-to* (-u) `origin/master` branch. Now, *git push*, *git pull* commands should work.

```
$ git checkout def
$ git branch -u origin/master
```